# How do you convert a python script that reads a text file into a working exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I created an application that reads a text file to get a digit (1 or 0) to execute some code (it runs like a save file since I want the value to be changed permanently, not just while the script is running), but when I use `pyinstaller` to convert it to a standalone exe file I get a `Fatal Error` saying that it cannot run the script. Previous compilations from before I added this feature worked, so I know it's something to do with reading that text file.

Note: I tried using a `.py` file instead of a `.txt`. While it worked as a script, the same error came up after compilation.

this is what I type into an elevated command prompt:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data save.txt;.' file.py
```

Comment: What libraries are you using in your project?

Comment: Do not paraphrase the error. Show us the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit the data files that you have bundled with your application using `--add-data` in `pyinstaller`'s `--onefile` method as it unpacks all the files into a temporary directory when executed, therefore the file wiil not be found in the current directory as the application demands, so you end up with the `Fatal Error`.

To get around this, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) post, use that function in your code and send your relative path into it, so as to get the absolute path of the file when the application is run. Remember, the changes that you make will be lost after you close the application, as these files are treated as "data files", they are not intended to be modified, so the binary will create a new copy of initial file on every application launch.

If you want it to permanently be stored somewhere, you can implement the file creation (if it doesn't exist) form the script itself, by creating a directory in the `AppData` folder and save the file there.

Comment: This worked for me. I opted to make a save file in the root folder using the "pickle" module. But when compiled only the save function occurs properly (after which a restart of the file is needed). After some testing I found that it runs the code all the way through but then shuts down before anything can happen. What's meant to happen is a box appears and you check a don't show again tickbox and click OK to save a value so that it skips over this next time the program is run but it just loads and nothing appears and then shuts down. I can't even get a glimpse of it in task manager. Any ideas?

Comment: @Atristamez That makes up a new question on its own, just ask a new question with these details and your code snippet for reference, I'd be glad to help you out there.